# Admob Video Reward clicks verification

Tags: android, click, admob, rewardedvideoad

I've a game with one rewarded video admob ad unit. Tested ok.
after uploading to google play, there are lot of impressions but zero clicks.

my Questions: Is there any way to setup an event or statistics to calculate number of user clicks then compare to admob output? Your suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have ads implemented via AdMob, easiest solution would be to integrate Firebase analytics and log individual video clicks like this:

```
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
// log an event
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("event_detail", myParam);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("video_click", params);
```

Insert the code above so that it gets executed when user clicks on a video and gets rewarded. This provides you the data that you can compare to your AdMob output.

Relevant Firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events

I have a project with Firebase analytics and AdMob ads, here's what it looks like

[image: Analytics example]

Comment: This is what I am exactly searching for. I am going to implement it. Thanks.

Comment: Might wanna mark it as correct answer then, no pressure though

Comment: What should be the action when getting events of user watched video ads and got rewarded but not reflected in Admob report? appreciated.

Comment: To be specific, Admob show impressions but zero Clicks, however firebase show events for watching & rewarding. appreciated.